# Java System.runFinalization() on windows server 2012

Tags: java, windows, jvm

I have an application that runs some native code from a dll. The native code creates many objects and occupies all the ram. In my java application, I keep checking the available RAM (Physical) and when a certain level reached, I call System.runFinalization() which of-course takes some time but frees up the memory that was occupied by the objects from native code that has no alive reference.

Now the issue is that this works just fine on Windows 7, but my client uses Windows Server 2012. When System.runFinalization() executes on server, the memory is not released immediately (as it does on windows 7) but it takes about 5 minutes to release all memory and application keeps waiting for the execution of System.runFinalization() for this much time. Please note that on Windows 7, the release of memory is not immediate either but still it is completed in just a few seconds. Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by *"the memory is not released immediately"*? Garbage-collected and thus available as part of the managed heap or released back to the OS? *"The native code creates many objects "* java objects (via JNI) or C++ objects? You should describe your scenario more accurately.

Comment: Immediately means it doesn't reflect in task manager, it just stops increasing. System.runFinalization doesn't release the control until the memory is freed up in about 5 minutes and then next statement in code is executed.

Comment: does it consume CPU cycles while running finalization? does it page in memory?

Comment: No, it doesn't consume CPU much (like it does on Win7). I am not sure what "does it page in memory" means.

Comment: check your system stats (e.g. via process explorer or windows' resource counters). paging in = loading from swap

Answer (score 0):

From JavaDocs :

```
public static void runFinalization()
```

> Runs the finalization methods of any objects pending finalization.
>   Calling this method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend
>   effort toward running the finalize methods of objects that have been
>   found to be discarded but whose finalize methods have not yet been
>   run. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual
>   Machine has made a best effort to complete all outstanding
>   finalizations.

There is no guarantee that when `finalize()` will be called or even if it will be called.

Comment: I understand that, but in my case there is 16G ram on server which is fully (almost) occupied and when I call runFinalization method, the ram is released in about 5 minutes and then runFinalization returns the control to program and next statement is then executed.